# Event listener does not work with pre-defined function as parameter

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm a beginner and I have just tried to do this:

```
ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Hi");
});
```

This works. I understand that this is an anonymous function. However, when I try to give a definition of this function beforehand and pass it in like so, it won't work:

```
function myFunc(e) {
  console.log("Hi from myFunc");
}

ul.addEventListener("click", myFunc(e));
```

I do not understand what the difference is. The error reads:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
> at javascript.js:29

Comment: In the second one, you're calling (executing) the function, not passing it a function reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the reference of the function, not the result of it's execution. It will call your function when `click` event will be fired. It is the same as you pass through an anonymous function, in 2 cases you pass only the reference of the function.

```
function myFunc(e) {
  console.log("Hi from myFunc");
}

ul.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
```